# What is the idiomatic way to do a long series of flatMaps in Scala?

Tags: scala

I know that a for yield is converted to a series of flatMaps followed by a final map. I find myself frequently wanting it to end instead in a final flatMap.  My workaround so far has been to do a for yield followed by a flatten like the following:

```
val aOpt = Some("a")
val bOpt = Some("b")
def fakeComplexFunc(s1: String, s2: String): Option[String] = Some(s1 + s2)
(for {
    a <- aOpt
    b <- bOpt
} yield {
    // Pretend this is a long block with lots of stuff in it
    fakeComplexFunc(a, b)
}).flatten
```

Is there a better way to do this? Is there any sort of best practice for cases like this? Have I done something drastically wrong if I end up in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could bind the result of `fakeComplexFunc` and yield it:

```
for {
  a <- aOpt
  b <- bOpt
  c <- fakeComplexFunc(a, b)
} yield c
```

Comment: Ah yes!  This is definitely true for my original toy example and I will definitely go back and change my code to this pattern where I can.  What if the yield block is longer though? Thanks for such a swift answer!

Comment: The yield block should just be the assembly of data to yield, not another operation on another Option/Collection/Future

Comment: Interesting. Can you expand on that? So, if you do have more operations and such, would you just make a function for that and put it in the for block?

Comment: This works up until you start mixing options and futures, or futures and seqs.. then it gets kind of bad ;(

Comment: @bwawok - Yes, although that's because monads in general do not compose, it's not a limitation of `for` comprehensions in particular.